# Getting Undefined DSC resource 'SqlSetup' even when the module is installed

Tags: sql-server, powershell, importerror, dsc, powershell-dsc

I am trying to install SqlServer via DSC, but I keep hitting this error

```
Exception calling "NewScriptBlock" with "1" argument(s): "At line:10 char:5
+     Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'SqlServerDsc'
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Could not find the module 'SqlServerDsc'.

At line:438 char:9
+         SqlSetup 'InstallDefaultInstance'
+         ~~~~~~~~
```

My DSC configuration snippet looks like this

```
Configuration InstallSoftware
{
param
(
    $ComputerNames
)
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
Import-DSCResource -Module SqlServerDsc

Node $ComputerNames
{
    WindowsFeature 'NetFramework45'
    {
        Name   = 'NET-Framework-45-Core'
        Ensure = 'Present'
    }

    SqlSetup 'SqlInstall'
    {
        InstanceName        = 'localhost\mssql2019'
        Features            = 'SQLENGINE'
        Action              = 'Install';
        SourcePath          = 'C:\SQL2019'
        SQLSysAdminAccounts = @('Administrators')
        DependsOn           = '[WindowsFeature]NetFramework45'
    }  
}

InstallSoftware
```

I am quite positive that the SqlServer has been installed in the remote server.

1. Get-DscResource -Module SqlServerDsc returned the list of resources
2. And the folder exists in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServerDsc

Any feedback/advice is highly appreciated.
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: It might be there, but it might not be usable. What does `Test-ModuleManifest -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServerDsc\SqlServerDsc.psd1"` (or the appropriate path) report?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
How is it possible that it might not be usable?   It's so weird. 
I ran the Test-ModuleManifest, and I noticed that the ExportedCommand is empty.    
  

`PS C:\Windows\system32> Test-ModuleManifest -Path "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServerDsc\15.2.0\SqlSer
verDsc.psd1"

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   15.2.0     SqlServerDsc`

Comment: [Test-ModuleManifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/test-modulemanifest) alows you to check for malformed module manifests, such as incorrect declarations, or version number mismatches, either of which could yield the "Could not find the module 'SqlServerDsc'" error message. You could also try reinstalling the module with the `-Force` parameter to make sure there are no missing files and/or broken file system ACLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response @AlwaysLearning! 
I got it working by adding the module in the Azure Devops Module

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was already answered, and I'm not sure I'm following everything, but I'll typically create a wrapper function for copying resources around.  Something like below with flags for specifying path, server, credential, then helper stuff like changing max envelop size (if you haven't hit this, you will) and copying out my cert.  Below isn't the whole thing, but it'd at least make sure your module would copy.

```
{
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$localpath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$ServerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [PsCredential]$PsAdmin,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [boolean]$MaxEnvelope,
        [boolean]$CopyDscResources,
        [boolean]$RunDscTest,
        [boolean]$AddEncryptionCert
    )
    #Create Path if it doesnt exist
    if (!(test-path -path $localpath)) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $localpath
        }
        if ($MaxEnvelope -eq $true)
        {
            $so = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
            $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $PsAdmin -SessionOption $so 
            Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
                Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizeKb -Value 3072
            }
        }
        
        if ($CopyDscResources -eq $true)
        {  
            $so = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
            $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $PsAdmin -SessionOption $so 
            
            $paramsDefender = @{
                Path = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServerDsc'
                Destination = 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
                ToSession = $session
            }
            Copy-Item @paramsDefender -Recurse -Force
            
        }

        $Session2 = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ServerName.ToString() -Credential $PsAdmin
        Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -Path $localpath -CimSession $Session2 -Force
        Start-DSCConfiguration -Path $localpath -Cimsession $Session2 -Wait -Force -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
        if ($RunDscTest)
        {
            Test-DSCConfiguration -Path $localpath -Cimsession $Session2 -Verbose | Format-Table -AutoSize
        }
       
        
}

#Example run
RunRemoteDsc $localpath 'Some-Server' $PsLocalAdmin $false $true $false
```